# Splitting comma separated input from text box and converting it into an array

Tags: php, html

I have a standard text input box for a form.

If I was to put into that input box a series of numbers all separated by a comma I would then like to convert that post data into an array.

The input box would be a simple

```html
<input type="text" name="postcode_numbers" id="whatever>
```

if the person puts in that box a series of numbers but separated by , I would then like the postcode_numbers post variable to be an array with each number as a value.

For example if they put in the text box 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

I would like the post variable $_postcode_numbers to be an array with each number as a value. so it would look something like:

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 4
[3] => 5
[4] => 6
[5] => 7
```

So in a nutshell what php function should I be using to turn the post data into a comma separated array ?

I have had a look at a few functions but they aren't making a great deal of sense to me so if this has been asked before forgive me as I just didn't understand.

Comment: [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php): `$_postcode_numbers = explode(',', $_POST['postcode_numbers']);`

Comment: _“I have had a look at a few functions but they aren't making a great deal of sense to me so if this has been asked before forgive me as I just didn't understand.”_ - in such a case, you should tell us what you researched/read up on, and also explain what in particular you’re having trouble understanding. In this current form, this question is just a duplicate of something that has been asked about numerous times before already, with no apparent reason what the actual trouble in researching and/or implementing something so trivial yourself was.